# Analytic function not injective in any neighborhood of a point if the derivative at that point is zero?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be analytic in some neighborhood $U$ with $z_0 \in U$. I've read that if $f'(z_0) = 0$, then $f$ is not one-to-one in any neighborhood of $z_0$. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume the zero of $f'(zo)$ is of order $n \geq 1$. Then consider the Taylor series about $z_0$, which can be written as :   $$f(z_0)=(z-z_0)^n g(z) $$  , where $g(z) \neq 0$ in an open neighborhood of $z_0$ ( this is possible since zeros of a non-zero analytic function are isolated.)You can translate $f(z)$ so that it has a zero at $z_0$ , so that $n \geq 2$ above.

Now, $g(z)$ is non-zero in a ball $B(z_0,r)$ , with $r>0$ . A ball $B(z_0,r)$ is simply-connected, so that, by some results in Complex variables, $g(z)$ admits a log and so it admits an n-th root ; $n \geq 2$. Then we can rewrite the above formula as: $$f(z)=(z-z_0)^2g_1^2(z) $$

where $g_1(z)^2=g(z)$

Then $f(z)$ admits a square root about the ball  $B(z_0,r)$. Now, choose any two points $w,w'$ in $\partial B(z_0,r)$ , so that $w,w'$ are $\pi$-translates of each other (meaning that $w, w'$ are antipodes in $B$). Then $f(w)=f(w')$ and $f$ is not $1-1$.